# Parsing errors of JSON using jq

Tags: json, jq

I have a curl command which results in the following example json:

```
json={"id":"12345","key":"ABC-DEF","url":"https://google.com"}
```

Now, I want to parse this, and get the key out of it and store it in a variable. What I did was the following:

```
json={"id":"12345","key":"ABC-DEF","url":"https://google.com"}
ID=$(echo $json | jq '.key' )
```

But the above gives me a error as: `parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 4`. Can someone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: Look at the value of `$json`... what do you see?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to quote the input string so the shell doesn't do anything with your string

```
json='{"id":"12345","key":"ABC-DEF","url":"https://google.com"}'
ID=$(echo "$json" | jq '.key' )
```